# can i override text field did end editing to include a validation check

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, categories

How to override a delegate function of uitextfield such that it does the validation of entered text. ie i need to override the textfield did end editing method to perform validation and this should apply to all textfield in my project.can i do this using categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Validation should be handled in `textFieldShouldEndEditing:`, not `textFieldDidEndEditing:`. "should" methods are called before something finishes to allow validation. "did" methods are notifications of something that has already happened.

**EDIT** You would not use a category on `UITextField` for this. There are lots of good solutions.

- Have a single, shared `UITextFieldDelegate` for all of your text fields
- Subclass your delegates from a consistent superclass that implements this the way you want
- Put the shared logic into a function that your delegates call in order to avoid subclassing
- Put your shared logic into a singleton `TextFieldController` that all your text field delegates would reference.

It all depends on the kind of logic you need in this routine. But you shouldn't use categories to override existing methods.

Comment: sorry i meant textFieldShouldEndEditing,the problem is  i have around 50+ viewcontrollers and should i put validation in each of these viewcontrollers textfieldshouldend editing or can i put a general validation by using categories for uitextfield itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a general validation by using categories for textfield.

Again, as Rob says, it all depends on the logic your application needs.